# WPF: Modifying CollectionView from Dispatcher still throws errors

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have the following bit of code that modifies an observable collection of 'screens' whenever a user leaves.

```
void OnUserLeft(int roomId, int userId, string username)
    {
        client.ClientDispatcher.Invoke(
            (Action<int>)((id) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello before the storm!");
                var screensToCheck = client.Screens.Where(s => s.CpuId == id).ToList();
                screensToCheck.Each(s => client.Screens.Remove(s));
                Console.WriteLine("Hello there!");
            }), userId);
    }
```

This is wrapped in a call to the client's Dispatcher, supposedly to get past the threading issues related to CollectionViews. However, I still get the following exception:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

The Dispatcher you see above is set in the WPF application's MainViewModel (we're using MVVM), like so:

```
public Dispatcher ClientDispatcher
{
    get { return Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly "the client's dispatcher"?

Comment: Sorry, added a bit about the 'ClientDispatcher' to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx):

> Gets the Dispatcher  for the thread currently executing and creates a new Dispatcher  if one is not already associated with the thread.

It looks like you are accessing `CurrentDispatcher` *while not in your UI thread*, and invoking your operation on it (i.e., the Invoke has no effect at all because the thread you are in does not have a Dispatcher; a new one is created on the spot and the call goes to it).

You should be saving the value of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` at the point where you create the `Client` instances (assuming you are doing that from within the UI thread), for example:

```
class Client {
    Client() {
        this.OwningDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }

    Dispatcher OwningDispatcher { get; private set; }
}
```

If your `Client` instances are not created on the UI thread, you need some way of getting the correct value of `Dispatcher` over to them.

Comment: This is the first time we're actually trying to delete something, using the Dispatcher to do so. So you're saying that our Dispatcher probably wasn't implemented correctly in the first place? I'll try that out now.

Comment: Success! You sir, are brilliant.

Comment: I wouldn't call this the result of brilliance. I just read the documentation for the features the code uses carefully. :-)